# Divs are overlapping with Isotopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-isotope, overlapping

Im using isotopes for my page and my divs that have images are overlapping. 
This issue is only happening SOMETIMES the first time I access a page on my browswer and ALL the time on phone. It never happens when accessing the page locally though.

I already tried using .imagesLoaded but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Any recommendations?

http://orianadesigns.com/4foodesses

Comment: Try to provide some code along with your question...

Comment: The page link is provided at the end of the question

Comment: But that requires that we debug your whole application... If you can isolate the problem and give us the problematic code, the solution might come faster...

Answer (score 0):

Unloaded images can throw off Isotope layouts and cause item elements to overlap. imagesLoaded resolves this issue.
You need to install [imagesLoaded.js](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) and then call isotope like this:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// init
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
 // options
itemSelector: '.box',
layoutMode: 'masonry'
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving the images a fixed width/height solved this problem for me.